# reading "/proc/bus/input/devices" programmatically

Tags: linux, sysfs

Is there a way to read contents `/proc/bus/input/devices` programmatically using some `sysfs` structures ?

I know I can parse the file and get values. But I am looking if there is a better method.

Answer (score 1):

There is. You can use `libsysfs`. Here is paper from IBM about it's API etc. - [Libsysfs - a programming interface to gather device information in Linux](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liaav/libsysfs-linuxconfau2004.pdf)

That being said, it is discouraged by Linux kernel developers - [Rules on how to access information in the Linux kernel sysfs](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/sysfs-rules.txt)

> Do not use libsysfs   It makes assumptions about sysfs which are not true. Its API does not   offer any abstraction, it exposes all the
>   kernel driver-core   implementation details in its own API. Therefore
>   it is not better than   reading directories and opening the files
>   yourself.   Also, it is not actively maintained, in the sense of
>   reflecting the   current kernel development. The goal of providing a
>   stable interface   to sysfs has failed; it causes more problems than
>   it solves. It   violates many of the rules in this document.

Comment: If it's not recommended probably wouldn't use it then. But do thanks for sharing the link. It's indeed informative